# JSF Ajax Navigation timeout

Tags: ajax, jsf, navigation, timeout

I'm using a selectonemenu combined with ajax to navigate.

JSF code

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{navigator.outcome}">                      
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select page..." />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="page1" itemLabel="Page 1" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="page2" itemLabel="Page 2" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="page3" itemLabel="Page 3" />
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{navigator.navigate}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Managed bean:

```
public void navigate() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     NavigationHandler navigationHandler = context.getApplication()
            .getNavigationHandler();

    navigationHandler.handleNavigation(context, null, outcome
            + "?faces-redirect=true");
}
```

I have an issue where if I leave the page open for a very long time (maybe a few hours) the ajax navigation seems to stop working. Is there some kind of timeout?

Comment: It's session timeout. And it's not only ajax requests, every type of requests becomes invalid until you re-access to the page.

Comment: How do you cope with this? Will form submit not work either?

Comment: This problem will go if you use the approach as proposed in this answer on your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008487/jsf-selectonemenu-navigation

Comment: I couldn't use that as I need it to render properly in the iphone using the native <select> scroll renderer.

Comment: @BalusC does the timeout issue only happen with Ajax? If I have a submit button will that work?

Comment: No, you're basically getting a `ViewExpiredException`, but not dealing with it in any way in case of ajax requests. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored/3642969#3642969 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203195/session-timeout-and-viewexpiredexception-handling-on-jsf-primefaces-ajax-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using ajax navigation use the following:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{navigator.outcome}" onchange="window.location =this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">                      
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select page..." />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="page1" itemLabel="Page 1" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="page2" itemLabel="Page 2" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="page3" itemLabel="Page 3" />

</p:selectOneMenu>
```

This works even if the session times out.