# Drop down list box of links to a page which immediately redirects the user on change

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to have a drop down list box of links to a page so that users can select it and immediately be redirected to that page. How can I achieve this? Is there any such component in PrimeFaces?

Comment: You can just try it and see if it works. If this can not work you can use p:datatable and selectOneMenu. You can see examples in showcase

Comment: Do you want to navigate as soon as user selects the Page name in Dropdown? or user has to click the button after selecting Page from Dropdown?

Comment: i need to navigate as soon as the user selects the page name.

Comment: im not even able to find the dropdown option there.

Comment: You have put a completely wrong in the title "Is it possible to use dropdown in panelgrid"? Of couse it is possible. You can even try it yourself. I fixed the wrong title based on the question body.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSF SelectOneMenu navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008487/jsf-selectonemenu-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

You could put the text as the display item and the hyperlink as the selectitem.  If you do "onselect" you can go to the hyperlink from your javascript... I think.